# Sufficient (or sufficient and necessary) conditions for a set of vectors to span $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Consider a set of vectors $k\times 1$ $$x_1,x_2,...,x_n$$ I want to check whether this set of vectors spans $\mathbb{R}^k$.

How can I do it? Are there sufficient (or sufficient and necessary) conditions? This question is strictly related to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46649/conditions-for-vectors-to-span-a-vector-space) but I do not understand whether the fact that my vector space is $\mathbb{R}^k$ simplifies things or not. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Let me reformulate my question. Thank you

Comment: You can compute the rank of the matrix $M = [x_1 \ldots x_n]$, using Gaussian elimination (or, much less efficient but theoretically useful, computing the determinants of its minors). It is necessary and sufficient that the rank of $M$ is $\geq k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the relevant [homogeneous system of $k$ equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems) with $n$ unknown. This system of equations have nontrivial solution if and only if $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ span $\mathbb R^k$ .

\begin{cases}
x_{11}y_1+...+x_{1n}y_n=0\\
x_{21}y_1+...+x_{2n}y_n=0\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
x_{k1}y_1+...+x_{kn}y_n=0\\
  \end{cases}

Comment: Thank you, what's the relevant system?

Comment: @STF I added details.

Comment: thanks! Is this equivalent to $[x_1 ... x_n]$ having rank $\geq k$?

Comment: @STF Yes. Otherwise this equation have no solution or have only trivial solution.