# If $V$ is a vector space with dimension $n$ then a set of $n$ vectors of $V$ spans $V$ if an only if they are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that if $V$ is a vector space with dimension $n$ then a set of $n$ vectors of $V$ spans $V$ if an only if they are linearly independent

This seems to be a widely known basic fact in linear algebra. I have not seen a proof showing this though. Please be thorough and prove every step.

Thank you very much in advance!

note: proving this would mean you would only need to satisfy one of two conditions to prove a set of vectors is a basis, contrary to what this Wikipedia page may be implying: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)

Comment: "Contrary to what Wikipedia page may be implying". **IF** you know the dimension *and* can count, then only one of the two is necessary because it implies the other. It doesn't contradict anything, because you are using extra information (the dimension of the space). And as I told you when you [asked for a proof in a comment in a 10+ year old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/46653/742) this fact is in literally every linear algebra textbook in existence. If you have "not seen a proof", then you haven't even cracked open a book on the subject.

Comment: In the very Wikipedia page you quote, if you go down to [Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Properties), the last two bulleted items are exactly what you are asking a proof of. Yet you claim it is "contrary to what this Wikipedia page may be implying." You really need to read through the material first.